# Origin of selected group of vertices is in odd position, why?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools, origin

The pictures are pretty much self explanatory:[image]

Points of the circle are clearly equally distributed but still when I select them all in edit mode the origin of selection is not at the center of the circle! And this creates great problem like asymmetrical scaling as shown below:[image]

So why is this happening and how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: weird, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot I see that you have selected 147 vertexes.

[image]

But it's looks like your circle has 32 vertexes. So I conclude that some of vertexes are off screen. But if it's not so, I think some vertexes are "doubles", that means you have several vertexes on same position. In this case you can:

1. Remove double vertexes (menu <kbd>W</kbd> -> Remove Doubles)
2. Or use **Bounding Box center** instead of **Median point** as a center of transformation (<kbd>,</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: That was the problem! It solved, thanks a lot.